# make_shared and emplace functions

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I was trying to find some easy way to emplace elements in a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` but couldn't come with anything. `std::shared_ptr` takes pointers as parameters, so I can still write this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.emplace_back(new int(10));
```

However, I don't want to use `new` by hand if possible, and would rather like to use `std::make_shared` if possible. The problem is that if I really want to use it, I have to use `push_back` instead and lose the advantage of in-place construction:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<int>(10));
```

Is there any way to get the advantages of both `emplace_back` and `std::make_shared`? If not, is there a guideline I should follow in such a case?

**EDIT:** Actually, I asked this question, but had an unrelated problem. Andy's answer is the good one and there isn't any actual problem with using both `emplace` functions and `std::make_shared` at once.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could let in-place move construction to occur:

```
vec.emplace_back(std::make_shared<int>(42));
```

Comment: Didn't he just say he couldn't do that?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Don't worry, that was just me being dumb and forgetting about the template parameter in `make_shared` when I first tried it. Actually, my question was as dumb as possible, everybody should just forget about it. I unintentionally asked a question about a problem when I had another one.

Comment: @Morwenn: This solution is indeed functionnal, but I would suspect it to be equivalent to a push_back, with the drawback of being less explicit. `emplace`family of methods are originally intended for in-place construction of values, without copy nor moves (cf. [std::queue::emplace(...)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/emplace)), allowing to avoid the creation of a temporary. When you actually want to copy construct from a temporary (what is happening here), I think `push` family of methods are the canonical way of doing things. Anyway, the compiler could (or not) elide copies.